# Mapping all css resources to a single folder using SpringMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, staticresource

Is there any way to map all css resources so that they are all served from /css folder from SpringMVC?
Ex. `/login/sampleUser/ie.css` maps to `/css/ie.css`

I have been trying using `<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" >`, but seems not to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be use the [Tuckey Url Rewrite Filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). There you can define complexer rewrite rules.

```
 <!-- I do not know if this fiter works (correctly), but it should
      demonstrate how it works-->
 <rule>
    <!-- redirect everything that ends with .css
         to resources, with same file name -->
    <from>/(.*)/$.css</from>
    <to type="redirect">/resouces/$1</to>
 </rule>
```

Comment: Interesting. Is there any way to rewrite using the servlet context? 

Ex. `http://localhost:8080/myContext/anyUser/css/ie.css` to `http://localhost:8080/myContext/css/ie.css`? 

All the examples seem to map to root directly. Ex. `http://localhost:8080/myContext/anyUser/css/ie.css` to `http://localhost:8080/css/ie.css`

Comment: The Tuckey Url Rewrite Filter works within you Application, so you can not rewrite to an other application.

Comment: Actually, you can and that's what happens when you "redirect" in your example. The correct rule should be something like this:

 `<rule>
  <from>.+/css/(.*)$</from>
  <to type="forward" last="true">/css/$1</to>
 </rule>`